# Accessing multi php array values

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm trying to access elements in array.

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'requests_users' => array(
            'request_id' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'ct' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'requests_users' => array(
            'request_id' => '2'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'ct' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'requests_users' => array(
            'request_id' => '4'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'ct' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'requests_users' => array(
            'request_id' => '5'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'ct' => '2'
        )
    )
)
```

By using for loop (under)

```
for($row=0;$row<count($list);$row++){
    echo $list[$row]['requests_users']['request_id'];
}
```

I could get request_id values.
However, I'm having a trouble getting a **'ct'** values.

Can you guys help me how to print **'ct'** values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about like this..

```
for($row=0;$row<count($list);$row++){
    echo $list[$row]['requests_users']['request_id'];
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $list[$row][0]['ct'];
}
```

try this. 
should work

Comment: Thank You for helping me. But do you know the way by using nested for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can get **"ct"** value :

```
for($row=0;$row<count($list);$row++){
    echo $list[$row][0]['ct'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below code

```
for($row=0;$row<count($list);$row++){
    echo $list[$row]['requests_users']['request_id'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $list[$row][0]['ct'];
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access an elements of above array you can use following recursive function:

```
 public function _convertToString($data){
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
                $this->_convertToString($value);
        }else{
            echo $key .'->'.$value;
        }
    }
}
```

you can call above function in following way:

```
$str = array(
      "data" => "check",
        "test1" => array(
          "data" => "Hello",
            "test3" => array(
                "data" => "satish"
            )
        ),
        "test2" => array(
            "data" => "world"
        )
    );


    $this->_convertToString($str);
```

You can modify output or recursive function to meet your requirements. Can you add original array in your question, I mean not var_dump() so that I can use that directly and modify code in my answer, if needed.